# How to get session id from data provider class in SAP Gateway?

Tags: backend, abap, sap-gateway

I am trying to find out how could I get information about external session id? I see it on a very top of the abap stack:
[image]

However, did not find any way to access this variable in the Data Provider Class. Do you have any tipp?

Comment: What is Data Provider Class?

Comment: Hi Suncatcher, it is part of Gateway service for SAPUI5 application backend. Here is the link which explains it a little: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3554185

Comment: OK, so as it is about SAP Gateway I corrected title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session_id is actually a static attribute specified in the IF_HTTP_SERVER interface. Because of the way in which ABAP sessions work, it is not possible to have two HTTP requests processed simultaneously in the same ABAP session, so I guess it makes sense to have the session_id as static.

Anyway, you can do something like this in your DPC_EXT class to obtain the session:

```
DATA(lv_session) = cl_http_server=>if_http_server~session_id.
```

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and came to the same solution as Serban provided. However, I hoped that sending multiple requests from the same browser window would have the same session id -- what is my understanding of session ids BTW. Which does not seem to be the case: subsequent odata calls from the same browser window to the same service (actually the exactly same service calls) showed always different sessionids in the debugger. So I think the sessionid on abap side is not really useful.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is due to the stateless communication between SAP Gateway Frontend and the OData-Backend (in other words, for the backend it is a new session for every incoming request).

I don't know how this behaves if frontend and backend components are on the same system though.